# Capture existing cookie of browser, with python

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

How can I capture existing cookies from my browser (current session on a certain site) to use with requests in python?

Comment: Have you looked at your browser's developer tools?

Comment: I'm developing a script to do some tasks on a site, but the sessions expires every 15 minutes, so i have to get the new cookie... that's why i'm trying to retrieve the cookie also in python

Answer (score 1):

You can't get cookies from your browser, due to security purposes. If you want to get cookies to your python script you should get it by `requests`.

```
req = requests.get("http://example.com")
```

And `req.cookies` will have your cookies objects

To send cookie objects you can create a simple dictionary with cookies and send it via necessary request:

```
cookies = { "id": "516561346236234" }
requests.post("http://example.com/send", cookies=cookies)
```

---

P.S. But you can get cookies by your hands using dev tools or plugins like EditThisCookie or CookieInspector.

Answer (score 0):

for future users, this is now possible, using:

https://github.com/borisbabic/browser_cookie3

an example with requests:

```
import requests, browser_cookie3
s = requests.Session()
s.cookies.update(browser_cookie3.chrome())
u = 'https://myurl'
r = s.get(u, headers=headers)
```

this will load all the cookies i have in my current chrome session